# How to typeset hh:mm:ss time format in math mode?

Tags: spacing, typography, siunitx

What's the correct way to typeset a daytime in the format hh:mm:ss in math mode?

For example in `$2:13,12\,\mathrm{min} = \SI{133,12}{s}$`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do this with `siunitx`, so I'll explain how I do it with a different package.

I use the [`datetime` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime). (I loaded both `datetime` and `siunitx` to the same document, and didn't get any conflicts, so you should be okay using both at the same time.) First I add the lines

```
\usepackage{datetime}
\settimeformat{hhmmsstime}
```

to my preamble, which load the package, and select the HH:MM:SS format (more formats can be found [in the package documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime/datetime.pdf)).

Then the command `\currenttime` prints the current time; for example, "14:10:37", or I can print a specific time with `\formattime{12}{29}{37}`, which prints "12:29:37".

Since the spaces around the colons get expanded in a maths environment, e.g., "14 : 10 : 37", you might want to embed the time command in an `\mbox{}`, e.g.

```
$\mbox{\formattime{12}{29}{37}}$
```

This puts the time in a maths environment, and keeps consistent spacing with the rest of the document.